# Photos disappeared from iCloud after upgrading to iPhone X

Tags: icloud

I had an iPhone 5C for 4 years - all photos were backed up on iCloud. I know this 100% for sure.

I upgraded to the iPhone X and set up the new phone from the most recent backup. None of the photos came over into my phone, but I didn't think anything of it.

I just now went to iCloud and it says I only have 37 photos - I know I had over 500. All of the 37 are recent, but are from BEFORE the upgrade, so I know they backed up from my old phone recently.

Where are all my other iCloud photos and how can I get them back if they are gone? 
Please help! Thank you so much!

Comment: P.S. I did find another 126 photos from the Recently Deleted. But I know those are recent photos from the last few months. I was able to recover the ones I wanted, but I don't understand how/why those ended up in the Recently Deleted section anyway...